# Apple Watch Not Allowed to be Activated by New Owner

Tags: icloud, apple-watch, watchos

I recently purchased a used Apple Watch.  The previous owner had already unsynced the apple watch from their phone and removed it from their iCloud account. However when I try to sync it to my phone it said that this Apple Watch was still liked to their Apple ID.

What can the both of us do?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily ask Apple's servers if a piece of hardware is currently locked:

- https://www.icloud.com/activationlock/

On e procedural side, https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205009 covers the unlocking process, but the seller needs to log into iCloud.com and delete that watch from their account.

They use the settings web app and "Under My Devices, click the Apple Watch that was sold and then click the X"

Should take them 5 minutes or less on a computer to sort that out.

Comment: Yes, they have already done that. They have sent me a photo of it also so I know that is has been done.

Comment: @RyanWestcott Bummer. They might need to write aletter to Apple or work with Apple support.  You are going to find it hard to get Apple to release someone else's hardware lock.